# Rollup including unneeded dependancies and missing a function in output

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, rollupjs

I'm using `rollup` for the first time and it's producing some unexpected results. Below I have the three files in my example along with the output from `rollup` and the kind of output I'm looking for.

[Here's a repo with my complete example.](https://github.com/reggi/testing-rollup)

I have three files `01.js`, `02.js`, `03.js`.

**01.js**

```
import { fakePromise } from './02'

export default fakePromise
```

**02.js**

```
import { map } from 'lodash'
import { stupidReference } from './03'

export function fakePromise (str) {
  return stupidReference(str)
}

export function fakeMap (arr) {
  return map(arr, item => item + ' is stupid')
}
```

**03.js**

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

export function stupidReference (str) {
  return Promise.resolve(str)
}
```

This is what `rollup` is returning. **(actual)**

```
import { map } from 'lodash';
import Promise from 'bluebird';

function fakePromise (str) {
  return stupidReference(str)
}

export default fakePromise;
```

This is what I'd expect rollup to return. **(expected)**

```
import Promise from 'bluebird';

function stupidReference (str) {
  return Promise.resolve(str)
}

function fakePromise (str) {
  return stupidReference(str)
}

export default fakePromise;
```

I was under the impression that rollup would shake out all the dependencies that you didn't need in your project. However you can see the **actual** output also includes an unneeded dependency `lodash`, and it's also missing another internal function `stupidReference`.

I'm curious as to why this isn't working as I expected. I'm also curious if I'm using the `rollup` tool correctly. If this is not the intended use, I would really love to find a tool that does achieve the functionality I'm looking for. I'd like to provide a function (or a file like `01.js` above) and have only the code necessary to run that function.

**Update 1**

Unsure what's happening with my code, but the editor on the rollup site is capable of pulling in another file and following the tree down. [Here's a link to exactly what I have.](http://rollupjs.org/#%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22format%22%3A%22cjs%22%2C%22moduleName%22%3A%22myBundle%22%2C%22globals%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22modules%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22main.js%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22%2F%2F%20ES6%20modules%20let%20you%20import%20all%20of%20another%20module's%5Cn%2F%2F%20exports%20as%20a%20namespace...%5Cnimport%20*%20as%20assert%20from%20'.%2Fassert'%3B%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20...but%20we%20can%20statically%20resolve%20this%20to%20the%5Cn%2F%2F%20original%20function%20definition%5Cnassert.equal(%201%20%2B%201%2C%202%20)%3B%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22assert.js%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22import%20%7B%20format%20%7D%20from%20'.%2Fmodule_1'%5Cn%5Cnexport%20function%20equal%20(%20a%2C%20b%2C%20msg%20)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ctif%20(%20!msg%20)%20msg%20%3D%20format(%20'%25s%20does%20not%20equal%20%25s'%2C%20a%2C%20b%20)%3B%5Cn%5Ctif%20(%20a%20!%3D%20b%20)%20throw%20new%20Error(%20msg%20)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnexport%20function%20ok%20(%20value%2C%20msg%20)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ctif%20(%20!msg%20)%20msg%20%3D%20format(%20'%25s%20is%20not%20truthy'%2C%20value%20)%3B%5Cn%5Ctif%20(%20!value%20)%20throw%20new%20Error(%20msg%20)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22module_1.js%22%2C%22code%22%3A%22export%20function%20format%20(%20str%2C%20...args%20)%20%7B%5Cn%5Ctreturn%20str.replace(%20%2F%25s%2Fg%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20args.shift()%20)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D%5D%7D)

**Update 2**

I realized that I may have configured babel incorrectly, I installed both the modules below as well as added `.babelrc` and `rollup.config.js`.

```
npm i rollup-plugin-babel babel-preset-es2015-rollup --save
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  entry: './01.js',
  plugins: [ babel() ],
  format: 'es6'
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015-rollup" ]
}
```

With this update the same output is still being produced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll kick yourself :-) The repo has a typo – `stupidReference` is spelt `stuidReference` in a couple of places. Fix those and it bundles fine. (If Rollup sees an identifier it doesn't know the origin of, it assumes it's a global rather than a typo.)

Lodash gets included even though its dependent function isn't included because Rollup can't know whether or not Lodash has side-effects. One option would be to include Lodash in the bundle (i.e. use [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve)) so that Rollup *can* see the code, but be aware that [tree-shaking Lodash is easier said than done](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/45#issuecomment-168127982), so the recommendation is to use `lodash-es` and import individual files:

```js
import map from 'lodash-es/map.js';
```

Comment: Hey Rich! I'm definitely kicking myself. As for `lodash` I'm a little confused. Because `lodash` isn't needed in my build (not used by any of the functions in `01.js`), it's an unused import. We wouldn't need to tree shake (include lodash's `map` function in the source and we wouldn't need it as a `npm` dependency for that bundle that `rollup` created.

Comment: `map` is an unused import (just opened a GH [issue](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/595) – ideally it would ditch that specifier) but `lodash` itself isn't, because of its potential side-effects. There's some discussion about an option for more aggressively discarding those side-effects, but it's very tricky

Comment: What I'm looking for is a little different. I'm interested in building a tool that breaks out specific file / function into a separate node module (building a relevant `packages.json` file). Ignoring unused deps and potential side-effects. I feel like rollup is only part way, [`acorn-umd`](https://github.com/megawac/acorn-umd) will help, and [`Standard`](https://github.com/feross/standard) has a way of knowing what variables aren't being used `'map' is defined but never used`. Need more research.